# Passing array of any type to postgres stored procedures using npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Is there a way of passing array of any type from c# code to postgres stored procedure as parameter using npgsql.

> Will anyarray or anyelement can be of any use in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "array of any type" (`anyarray`) is a [PostgreSQL pseudo-type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html) that's simply used to write functions which accept any area. It isn't a type which actually exists - you can't have a column of `anyarray`.

So to answer your question, you can use Npgsql to send an array of int, of text, or any other datatype to a PostgreSQL function which accepts `anyarray`. Npgsql has no knowledge about `anyarray` and doesn't care about it, it's just a PostgreSQL-side detail.

Answer (score -1):

Because of strong datatyping in Npgsql, I can't see any **good** way to accomplish this, but if you want a hack that is minimally offensive (as far as dynamic SQL/SQL injection), you can join the "anyarray" in C# and then split it in PostgreSQL.

```
object[] test = new object[] { "one", "two", 3, 4 };

NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(
    "select cardinality(regexp_split_to_array(:COMBINED, E'\t'))",
    Connection);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("COMBINED", string.Join("\t", test));

int results = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Of course you need to pick a delimiter that has the least chance of appearing in any of the values, which stinks.